# Change css of <td *matCellDef> in Angular sidenav

Tags: html, css, json, angular, html-table

```
 <th mat-header-cell id="tableHeader" *matHeaderCellDef> </th>
        <!-- Show headers-->
        <td mat-button id="dropDown" href="javascript:void()" (click)="element.isExpanded = 
        !element.isExpanded"
        *matCellDef="let element of docs"> {{element.name}}
        </td>
  </ng-container>
```

How do i change the color of the specific element.name that i am hovering/clicking? The way i have tried changes color of all elements at once. I am getting 'docs' from a JSON file which then displays headers in a sidenav which are clickable to drop down and display subheaders

I want 'Administration'(=element.name) to also change color, 'test' is the subheader to element.name
[see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M71Fs.png)

```
    <th mat-header-cell id="tableHeader" *matHeaderCellDef> </th>
    <!-- Show headers-->
    <td mat-button id="dropDown" href="javascript:void()" 
    (click)="element.isExpanded = !element.isExpanded"
    *matCellDef="let element of docs" [style.background- 
    color]="bkColor"> {{element.name}}
    </td>
    </ng-container>
```

This is what i do to change color of all cells, i would however like to change to bkColor only on the mat-buttons that i click on and then change back to original color when clicked once again.

I can also add #dropDown:hover in css, this allows me to change color of the hovered cell, i would however like to permanently change the color when the cell is clicked.

Doing it in TS only changes the color of the very first element.name

```
test() {
  var toggle = 
  document.getElementById("dropDown");
  toggle.style.background = "red";
  }
```

//Edit code below does not work either.

```
<td mat-button id="dropDown{{i}}" href="javascript:void()" (click)="element.isExpanded = !element.isExpanded"
      *matCellDef="let element of docs; index as i" (mouseenter)="changeColor(i)"> {{element.name}}
     </td>
```

TS:

```
 changeColor(index: number): void {
        const elem = document.getElementById('dropDown' + index);
        if (elem) {
          elem.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
        }
      }
```

Solution: For anyone who has set the multiTemplateDataRows property of mat-table to true, you can't use index. Instead you have use either dataIndex or renderIndex.

```
     <td
     mat-cell
     id="dropDown{{ i }}"
     *matCellDef="let element of docs; let i = dataIndex"
     href="javascript:void()"
     (click)="changeColor(i); element.isExpanded = 
     !element.isExpanded;">
       {{element.name}}
     </td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can not have more than one element with same id.

change related codes in html:

```
<td mat-button id="dropdown{{i}}" href="javascript:void()" 
(click)="element.isExpanded = !element.isExpanded"
*matCellDef="let element; index as i" [style.background- 
color]="bkColor" (mouseenter)="chanegeColor(i)"> {{element.name}}
</td>
```

and in your typescript file:

```
chanegeColor(index: number): void {
const elem = document.getElementById('dropdown' + index);
if (elem) {
  elem.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
}
```

}

there is an example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jpghrx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts).

Comment: It did not work. It still acts as if no changes were made. will add new code to post.

Comment: i dont know why it did not work for you but i update my answer and put an example there. check that link to find your problem(click event on weight cells will change backround color)

Comment: Im thinking it has to do with the structure of my Json file. it looks like this:
{
      "name":"Administration",
      "isExpanded":false,
      "subjects":[
         {
            "name":"test",
            "content": "hello world it is me"
         }
      ]
   }
alerting elem in typescript is returning null